# How to create double exposure effect programatically in Android?

Tags: android, opencv

How to programatically create a similar effect to this:

[image]

I saw this answer from here: [Android Photography App Double Exposure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240161/android-photography-app-double-exposure) But it is so basic and there is no explanation how it should work; maybe OpenCv would have a better result? Does anyone have any idea on how to implement that?

Comment: The answer given in the post you linked seems good. Try to load 2 images (same size) as `Mat` objects and then add them with `Core.add`.

Comment: Can you share the two input images as well ?

Comment: it is just the first image in google for double exposure; I am looking to get at least a similar effect, just did not have any idea where to start, and no documentation on that even in opencv

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one image is thresholded (woman) and used as a mask for second image (lake and trees). Then both images can be added with some weights. You could start with both weights = 0.5 and then play around with them.